# Can you decode these pictures to identify the hidden treasure?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

Combination of these pictures represent a treasure:

[image]

### Can you identify it?

Comment: Is it not a rebus puzzle?

Comment: What are the first and last pictures meant to be?

Comment: First picture- beginning of a Race and last picture- wardrobe and clothes.

Comment: Is the line joining the race and the watch intentional?

Comment: Some clues would be greatly appreciated. The pictures are rather generic (except the almonds, perhaps) and could mean many things.

Answer (score 5):

They represent

> Gold. Race -> gold medal. Fish -> goldfish. Bowl of almonds -> not a clue. Watch -> gold watch. Thumbs up -> golden thumb. Clothes -> gold threads.

Thought I'd post a guess. I wouldn't be surprised if I'm not even close.

Comment: "gold almonds" turns up plenty of results.

Comment: Orthogonal thinking!  Indeed, I would say that the almonds are the only one which appears to be slightly golden of color, and therefore are the key to this interpretation — well, the visual one at any rate.